# Redirect URI Mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect, oauth-2.0

**I am unable to authorize my rails app**

```
I am unable to authorize my rails app with bigcommerce OAuth in staging/production server. The same configuration/code is working in development using ngrok.

Error message received: (bigcommerce) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials
```

**I'm using Rails '5.0.7.2'**
**I have a draft application with the temporary callback url set as**
**https://bplugin.giftpal.in/auth/bigcommerce/callback**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To encourage other users to help you with your issue, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).